# Get the Caller Playbook directory name in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two playbooks `pb1.yml` and `dir/pb2.yml`. I am calling `pb2.yml` from `pb1.yml` playbook. I need to print the name of the directory which called the `pb2.yml` playbook.

```
cat pb1.yml
---
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - debug: var={{ playbook_dir |basename }}

  - import_playbook: dir/pb2.yml

cat dir/pb2.yml
---
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - debug: var={{ playbook_dir |basename }}
```

In the following example , I am able to get the directory name of `pb2.yml` but I am interested to know the directory name of `pb1.yml` from `pb2.yml`.

```
home/monk>ansible-playbook pb1.yml
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "samples": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dir": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Expected result:

from pb2.yml, print `/home/monk/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the variable is properly expanded and the value printed with the parameter *`msg`*

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ playbook_dir|basename }}"
```

, or the variable is printed with the parameter *`var`* without expansion

```
  - debug:
      var: playbook_dir|basename
```

---

Explanation

The code *`{{ playbook_dir|basename }}`* evaluates to "sample" or "dir" respectively

```
tasks:
  - debug: var={{ playbook_dir|basename }}
```

Such variables are not defined and the play will fail

```
"samples": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

Quoting from [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html)

> var: A variable name to debug.Mutually exclusive with the msg option.
>   Be aware that this option already runs in Jinja2 context and has an implicit {{ }} wrapping, so **you should not be using Jinja2 delimiters unless you are looking for double interpolation**.

"Double interpolation" is actually "indirect addressing". The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    x: y
    y: z
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ x }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "y": "z"
}
```

Comment: but this does not answer how to get the caller dir name

Comment: You've already got it! It's in your output. It's "sample" or "dir" respectively.